# Convert any positive number to decimal $x$ such that $0\lt x \lt 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

This is a very basic question, I understand that.

So I have these numbers: 20, 0.75, 1.25. If you sort them, it would look like this:

```
20
1.25
0.75
```

I need to convert any number that's greater than 1 to a decimal that's less than 1 and greater than 0, and still sort like above.

So I thought about dividing 1 by that number. But naturally, that's not going to work with the 0.75, so 0.75 will be greater than 20.

So what formula can I apply to *any positive number* so that they all are less than 1 and greater than 0, and they still sort correctly with this new value (i.e. #1: 20, #2: 1.25, #3: 0.75)

Comment: Is there a minimum and maximum value that your numbers can take?

Comment: Part of the question says "any number that's greater than 1," and another part says "apply to any number."  You should probably reconcile these two different criteria, especially since the chosen answer fulfills one of them and not the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many approaches.  You need an increasing function that has a horizontal asymptote.  One simple one is $f(x)=\frac x{1+x}$.  When $x=0, f(x)=0$ and as $x$ gets large $f(x)$ goes to $1$.

Answer (score 4):

What about $\frac x{x+1}$? It's an increasing function with values in $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following function:

$$S(x) = \frac 1{1+e^{-x}}$$

This function has the following graph:

[image]

Now, if all of your values are non-negative, you will want to use the following function:

$$S(x) = \frac 2{1+e^{-x}} - 1$$